# Discrepancy in validation accuracy and validation loss during training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm training my CNN model with 14k+ images for 30 epochs and in the 28th epoch, I find an abnormal validation accuracy and loss as shown  below :

```
 - 67s - loss: 0.0767 - acc: 0.9750 - val_loss: 0.6755 - val_acc: 0.8412
Epoch 27/30
 - 67s - loss: 0.1039 - acc: 0.9630 - val_loss: 0.3671 - val_acc: 0.9018
Epoch 28/30
 - 67s - loss: 0.0639 - acc: 0.9775 - val_loss: 1.1921e-07 - val_acc: 0.1190
Epoch 29/30
 - 66s - loss: 0.0767 - acc: 0.9744 - val_loss: 0.8091 - val_acc: 0.8306
Epoch 30/30
 - 66s - loss: 0.0534 - acc: 0.9815 - val_loss: 0.2091 - val_acc: 0.9433
Using TensorFlow backend.
```

Can anyone explain why this happened?

Comment: Looks like you are overfitting. Can you share the network architecture and optimizer used.?

Answer (score 2):

To me it's looks like **overfitting**. Your training loss is approaching zero and training accuracy approaches 100, whereas validation loss and accuracy jump around.

I would recommend you to tune your **regularization** (dropout, l2/l1, data augmentation ...) or model capacity.

Usually, it's a good practice to have high-capacity model with tuned regularization.

Answer (score 0):

Like Arkady. A said, its strongly looks like overfitting. It means your model memorized the images so your accuracy raise and raise. But on validation data you achieve bad result.

Example: You memorize that 2*8=16  without understand how multiplication in math realy works. So for the question 2*8 you give as answer 16. But for 2*9=? you dont know what the anwser is.

How to avoid:

1. Use strong Image Augmentation like imgaug or augmentor.
2. Use Dropout Layer
3. Calculate and Save 2 Graphs for each epoch, one for train data Accuracy, one for     validation.Normaly both graphs going up at the beginning, and after epoch X  the validation graph start to jumping or decreasing. This epoch or epoch-1 is your last good state.
4. Use more metrics like ROC AUC
5. Use EarlyStop Callback with monitoring val_acc